# Google play game services Type a Number sample has issue with package name

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am trying to get the google game play services sample "Type a Number" to run but am having a hard time getting it to work. I follow the instructions of their [tutorial website](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart) and I try running the application after Step 1 part 6, but I get the following error

```
09-27 22:05:46.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.games.tanc/com.google.example.games.tanc.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.example.games.tanc.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.games.tanc-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.games.tanc-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

where the package has been renamed to: com.test.games.tanc as per the instructions in Step 1 part 5. I assumed that the application would not run unless I finished everything so I moved on to step 2. I went half way through step two and the app was still crashing so I tried to debug it and have not managed to find anything to correct that error.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Update: Here is the manifest

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.games.tanc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.example.games.tanc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Update 2: I updated the manifest file as suggested and the app id but am still getting this error:

```
 10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279): Process: com.test.games.tanc, PID: 20279
 10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.games.tanc/com.test.games.tanc.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.games.tanc.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.games.tanc-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.games.tanc-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.games.tanc.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.games.tanc-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.games.tanc-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-01 15:04:12.339: E/AndroidRuntime(20279):    at    dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
```

Update 3: One thing that has been bothering me is that there are no files under src for BaseGameUtils or the TypeANumber projects. 
[image: There is no drop down arrow by src]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse on Windows, you'll need to handle setting up the directory structure manually. (Linux and Mac can run the script mentioned in the other answers here).  To set it up you need to do the following (Replace TypeANumber with your sample of choice)

(Note: the xcopy command lines are from memory - so you'll want to verify they did what was expected)

1. Make a directory eclipse_compat

   `md eclipse_compat`
2. Make a directory for the sample code

   `md eclipse_compat\TypeANumber`
3. Copy the AndroidManifest.xml file to the new directory

   `copy BasicSamples\TypeANumber\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml eclipse_compat\TypeANumber`
4. Copy the resources (this should make a res directory in eclipse_compat\TypeANumber)

   `xcopy /e /i BasicSamples\TypeANumber\src\main\res eclipse_compat\TypeANumber`
5. Copy the source files

   `md eclipse_compat\TypeANumber\src`

   `xcopy /S BasicSamples\TypeANumber\src\main\java\*.* eclipse_compat\TypeANumber\src`
6. Copy the libs

   `md eclipse_compat\TypeANumber\libs`

   `copy Scripts\eclipse_aux\*.jar eclipse_compat\TypeANumber\libs`

From here can follow the rest of the instructions.

Also, you might want to double check the AndroidManifest.xml:

1. Make sure the package of your renamed class matches the package attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. Make sure the android:name attribute of the activity matches your full class name.

Comment: I have not touched anything in the src files since the tutorial did not mention them. Should I have changed the path of the classes in the tutorial to match the package name? Also I updated the OP with the manifest.

Comment: The android:name attribute of the activity should be com.test.games.tanc.MainActivity.  The app id from the games console needs to be updated in res/values/ids.xml

Comment: Thanks for the translation of the script. That seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Eclipse, but these samples are build for Android studio.  That is why you have no files under `src`.  You should follow the instructions for Eclipse in the [Github Readme](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples#if-youre-using-eclipse) which I will copy here for completeness:

#### If you're using Eclipse...

1. From the command line run Scripts/make_eclipse_compat.  This creates the directory structure needed to import the projects correctly.
2. Start Eclipse
3. Import the Google Play Services library project (available for download through the SDK manager):

   1. Click **File | Import | Android | Existing Android Code into Workspace**
   2. Select `SDK/extras/google/libproject/google_play_services/google_play_services_lib` (where `SDK` stands for the path where you installed your Android SDK)
   3. Click **Finish**
4. Import `eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils` **as a library**

   1. Click **File | Import | Android | Existing Android Code into Workspace**
   2. Select the `eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils` project
   3. Click **Finish**
   4. Right-click on `BaseGameUtils`, then click **Properties**
   5. In the project properties window, click the **Android** section
   6. Check the **Is Library** checkbox
   7. Add a reference to the `google_play_services_lib` project (click **Remove** to remove any broken references, then click **Add** to add the correct one)
5. Import the desired sample from the `eclipse_compat` directory (Project | Import | Android | Existing Android Source)
6. Go into the project properties window for that project (right-click, **Properties**) and check that this project has a reference to the `BaseGameUtils` project.

Your project should now compile. However, don't run it yet, since you still need to adjust your game's IDs
in order for the sample(s) to work.

Now jump to the *Modify IDs, compile and run* section and continue to follow the instructions there.

Comment: How would you do step one in Windows? Using the command line in Windows (i.e. going to the directory then selecting run make_eclipse_compat, doesn't seem to work)?

Comment: We are working on a script that does the same thing in Windows right now actually, sorry about the wait!

Comment: i have this error, when i try to do the step one ( both in Windows and in MacOsx ): this script must be run from the base directory of your working copy.
:/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you've followed this instruction -

```
In the Type-a-Number Challenge project (not BaseGameUtils), open AndroidManifest.xml and change the package name from com.google.example.games.tanc to a different package name of your own. The new package name must not start with com.google, com.example, or com.android.
```

Comment: I made no modifications to the BaseGameUtils project